# how parallel access to memory in PTLsim happens

Tags: caching, memory, cpu

I am performing research work on PCM using *PTLsim*. I find that there is a loop inside the function void MissBuffer::clock() in the file dcache.cpp. It implies that parallel access to memory or caches happens. But how can it happen with only a memory rank. In addition, the number of Level-1 D-cache has only  8 banks while the size of MissBuffer is 64. So the banks cannot explain the parallel access. I get confused. If I want to add some function such as record the write-memeory time, how can I do it ?